# What is the role of @Indexable in elasticsearch-osem?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm looking into integrating elasticsearch into my spring-jpa driven application.
For this purpose the [elasticsearch-osem](https://github.com/aloiscochard/elasticsearch-osem) project seems an amazing fit.
What I can't understand is what is the role of the `@Indexable(indexName = "someIndex")` annotation which is shown in the example from the introduction to the project.
What confuses me is the fact that in the same example it says:

> Then you can write objects to the ElasticSearch client:
>   node.client().prepareIndex(**"twitter"**, "tweet","1").setSource(context.write(tweet)).execute().actionGet();

Where "twitter" is the index-name.

I think my question is why should one also define an `@Indexable` on a field and why should they define an index-name?

Thanks

Comment: Are you having any luck with this project? Is it working for you? I would like to talk to you about it, at gearondATsbcglobal.net

Comment: @Dennis I ended up working without the project. Mainly because I realized the relational-document gap is not something it can solve for me but I have to solve it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source code I was able to see that the @Indexable is used to either supply aliases to the fields of indexed properties in indexed entities **or** to allow indexing of properties in un-indexed entities.
You can see this in the `getIndexableProperties` method in the `AttributeSourceImpl` type where it says in a comment:

> Searchable class properties are implicitly Indexable

Answer (score 2):

With `@Indexable` you say which fields should be included in the index. The `indexName` is the name of the field in the index. This is not the name of the index, which you set with your other call.

From Javadoc:

```
/**
* The name of the field that will be stored in the index. Defaults to the property/field name.
*/
    String indexName() default "";
```

Comment: Hi ynka, thanks for your answer. So you think it's only a mechanism to allow aliases for fields? That I'll be able to query the index for those fields later?

Comment: I do not think that it is only to allow aliases. I think that when you do not use '@Indexable', you will not be able to use the field while searching the index. Bear in mind, though, that I use lucene at work ;)

Comment: (or you will be able to use it, but it will be very slow)

Comment: Actually I looked through the source code and it's to allow indexing of properties where the entity itself is not searchable. I'll add a detailed answer.